# Дать дуба. Происхождение фразеологизма

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Почему просторечным синонимом слова "умереть" является выражение "дать дуба"?
Кому дать? Почему именно дуба? Если речь о дубовом гробе, то почему — дать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Справочная служба русского языка предлагает такие трактовки:
"Дать дуба — *груб. прост*. умереть. Есть две версии возникновения этого выражения.
1) Оборот возник на русской почве и связан с глаголом задубеть — "остыть, потерять чувствительность, сделаться твердым".
2) Выражение возникло на юге России. Можно предполагать, что под дубом хоронили умерших, а может быть, образ оборота и иной. Любопытно лишь то, что дерево — символ долголетия — стало использоваться для обозначения смерти".

Первый вариант мне нравится. Второй — кажется менее правдоподобным. Не только же под дубами хоронили. Вариант про "дубовый гроб" тоже интересный.

Что касается слова "дать"... Есть еще несколько устойчивых выражений: "дать леща", "дать дрозда", "дать петуха" (может, еще найдется). Получается значение совершённого действия как факта. А что именно свершилось — иносказательно "уточняет" последующее слово.

Answer (score 2):

Оно имеет под собою воинские и народные мотивы, ведь в понимании славян дуб – это одно из названий ладьи, лодки, которые  делались  из дубовых досок. Дуб в воде не гнил, а только крепчал.  «Смотреть в дуб» – быть при смерти, от языческого обычая погребения в ладье, отсюда же современное «дать дуба».

Comment: Даже если предположить, что верно всё, сказанное до последней запятой, непонятно, почему сделан такой вывод. Почему "дать", а не "познать" или, скажем, "купить"? Используется какая-то доисторическая логика?

Answer (score 1):

В древности на Руси знатных хоронили в гробах, выдолбленных в стволах срубленных дубов. Существовала большая дубовая роща с вековыми дубами. И, то ли при рождении, то ли при достижении определенного возраста, знатному человеку предоставляли еще при жизни дерево. Тем языком — давали дуба. Дальше — все ясно...

Comment: Просмотрел много сайтов на эту тему.Версий множество,но ни кто конкретно так и не ответил.Почему-ДАТЬ дуба?

Comment: *никто конкретно так и не ответил* - Надюшка ответила. Вполне осмысленное толкование, хотя и дискуссионное. Что касается вашего, то оно всего меньше объясняет, почему именно "дал".

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы в комментарий к *@Надюшка*, но автор давным-давно сюда носу не кажет.

Тут вот какой момент. Из пояснений в ответе *Надюшки* следует, что "дал" означает создал, воспроизвел (*дал петуха*), в крайнем случае — превратился. Это вполне обоснованное предположение, хотя и неочевидное. Но никак не "пошел", "перенесся" к чему-то.

То есть *дал дуба = задубел* она хорошо объясняет, а *пошел под дуб / в дуб* (гроб) — никак.

Answer (score 0):

Все варианты выше предполагают, что покойник дуб именно заберёт, например, на строительство гроба, ладьи и т. д. Так что не подходит слово "дать".
А вот случайно заметил в совершенно другой теме такое толкование: древние славяне сжигали  трупы,  а в  оставшейся  золе (в земле, естественно) садили жёлудь!
Вот оттуда и выражение: "дать дуба".

Answer (score 0):

Давайте для начала внимательно вчитаемся в выражение "дать дуба". Вернее, во фразу "Такой-то имярек дал дуба". Обратите внимание - не имяреку "дали дуба" (как тут выше кто-то писал... Вспомнилась история, когда кто-то из иностранцев русское выражение "дать по шапке" толковал как "выдать каждому по одному головному убору").
В-общем, не имяреку дали дуба, а именно сам имярек дал дуба в связи со своей смертью.
Есть такая мысль. Ну, действительно, гроб из дубового дерева - самый, что ли, "почётный" и "престижный" - поэтому дать не сосны, не липы, а именно дуба.
Отступление морфологического характера: дуб - предмет неодушевленный, следовательно, в винительном падеже (кого? что?) надо говорить не "дать дуба", а "дать дуб". Тем не менее, в разговорной речи в подобных фразах часто используется форма родительного падежа вместо винительного. Поэтому "дать дуба".
Итак, человека похоронили. Закопали в землю вместе с гробом, изготовленным из древесины дуба. Что может произойти с деревянной доской под землей в условиях подходящей влажности и температуры? Правильно - доска может прорасти (ботаника, вегетативное размножение растений и т.п., останавливаться не будем). А прорастет она в виде чего? Ясное дело - в виде дуба (а не ромашки какой-нибудь). И вот на могиле вырастает дуб. Выходит, умерший дал (природе, Земле, своим близким, всему человечеству) дуба.